# Using loop to create modicate dataframe

Tags: r

I have been struggling with finding a way to create a new data frame using a loop, where the main goal is to filter the data when is >= 0.5.
I´m using Rstudio; however, python is an option too.
Here is how looks like my data frame (csv file) and some lines of the script (incomplete):

```
df <- read.table(choose.files(), header = T, sep = ",", comment.char = "")

Site,Partition,alpha,beta,omega,alpha=beta,LRT,p-value,Total branch length
1,1,"0.000","0.000","NaN","0.000","0.000","1.000","0.000"
2,1,"0.060","0.046","0.774","0.048","0.049","0.825","0.000"
```

Then I use **select** function to take only two columns that interest me:

```
sdf <- subset(df, select = c("ï..Site", "alpha.beta"))

    
    ï..Site alpha.beta
1    1      0.000
2    2      0.048
...
```

Then I thought in use a loop to create a new csv file, when the second column has a value >= 0.5 print this value, it doesn´t have a value that satisfies this requisite pass and print a 0.
Here I try differents ways; obviously neither works for me. Here are the last lines that I tried.

```
for (i in names(sdf1)) {
  f_sdf1 <- sdf1[sdf1[, i] >= 0.5]
  write.csv(f_sdf1, paste0(i, ".csv"))
}
```

So in this post I´m looking for some ideas to generate this script. Maybe it´s simple, but in this case, I need to ask how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `subset` to filter your data as in

```
# first get some example data
expl <- data.frame(site = 1:10, alpha.beta = runif(10))
print(expl)

# now do the filtering
expl.filtered = subset(expl, alpha.beta >= .5)
print(expl.filtered)

# Now write.table or write.csv...
```